# ng-datepicker in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker

I am having a span tag which includes ng-datepicker

Instead of selecting the date from the picker, I manually enter the date as "9/1/19" or "09012019".

while using watch function i am unable to get these values in "nv or ov" refer below code.

Please suggest the possible ways so, that i can get the dates which were entered manually in "nv or ov"
 in watch function

Thanks in advance

```
<span ng-datepicker ng-model="value">
</span>

     $scope.$watch('value', (nv, ov) => {
                if (nv !== ov) {
                   //some code here
                }
            })
```

;

Comment: How can span have ng-model? ng-model is supposed to be bound to form-controls..

Answer (score 0):

ng-model work only in input element (input, select, textarea, select)